# How to make a column count by name and total amount of dataframe pandas?

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have the following dataframe in pandas:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Sensor': ['strain', 'water', 'water', 'ultrassonic', 'strain'], 
           'Total': [1,10,20,5,9],
           'Columns_3': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E']})

print(df)
Sensor     Total    Columns_3
strain      1      A
water       10     B
water       20     C
ultrassonic 5      D
strain      9      E
```

I'd like to do a count of the total amount of different sensors. So I tried to use `groupby()` as follows:

```
df_result = df.groupby(['Sensor', 'Total'])['Total'].sum()
```

The output of my code is:

```
  Sensor       Total
  strain       1         1
               9         9
  ultrassonic  5         5
  water        10       10
               20       20
  Name: Total, dtype: int64
```

However, I would like the output to be a dataframe (`df_result`) as follows:

```
print(df_result)

Sensor  Total_final
strain      10     
water       30        
ultrassonic 5
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you don't need total as part of the group by

```
df.groupby(['Sensor'])['Total'].sum()
```

```
Sensor
strain         10
ultrassonic     5
water          30
Name: Total, dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just `groupby` with `Sensor` only

```
 df_result = df.groupby(['Sensor'])['Total'].sum().reset_index()
```